# Decoding RSA data with PyCrypto with given modulus/exponents

Tags: python, delphi, google-app-engine, rsa

I'm porting a native (Win32, made in Delphi 5 with TP LockBox 2) app to Google App Engine and i'm currently struggling to get past RSA encryption/decryption. I have the Modulus and both exponents as a Tuple in my code like this:

```
rsa_key = ( 0xABABAB....ABABABL, 0xABABL, 0xABABABA...ABABAL)
```

Replacing the random "ABABA" with the proper values from my key. However, when i construct my RSA implementation with:

```
rsa = RSA.RSAImplementation().construct(rsa_key)
```

And then decrypt my data:

```
self.response.out.write(rsa.decrypt(serial[0:128]))
```

I just get gibberish. Is there something i might haven't taken into account when translating the Modulus/Exponents?

**UPDATE 18 Jan 2012**

I generated a key with OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl genrsa -out test.key 1024 -outform DER
```

And used the Base64 string to "import" the key with `RSA.importKey` and it worked. On the same key i extracted the modulus and exponents with the command:

```
openssl rsa -in prueba.key -text -modulus
```

And tried to use those values to `construct` a key with the specified tuple and worked. I'm going to double check my legacy key's values to verify if it is working as intended.

**FINAL UPDATE**

It seems my legacy app isn't generating good moduli/exponents. This would mean this is a non-issue. Disregard this post.

Comment: Check if a basic decrypt/encrypt works. Is rsa.decrypt(rsa.encrypt("Hello", 1)) == "Hello" ?

Comment: Do you construct the key with parameters mentioned under construct at https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/?

Comment: Either your key is wrong, or your data is wrong, or both.

Comment: @ib.lundgren indeed it doesn't work... maybe i extracted wrong the modulus and exponents

Comment: Just generated a key with OpenSSL. When loading the DER formatted key it worked witha a simple encrypt-decrypt. However, i used OpenSSL to extract the parameters of the key (Modulus and exponents) and it doesn't work when specifying the modulus and exponents directly with the `construct`handler.

Comment: Requesting this question to be closed because the problem was my legacy generator. Please vote for it to close.